# CSS: Rectangle side to round inside

Tags: css

How can I create the rounded side (not corner) to round inside?
I've thought about placing a white circle over it but then I figure there must be a cleaner way.

I tried this but it round outwards:

```
.box {
    width: 30em; height: 10em;
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 .75em .75em; 
    background: black;
}
```

It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well frankly i think we need to use another div to make it because its not possible to curve a div like this with css

Please refer the code below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box1">
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    width: 30em; height: 10em;
    border-radius: 0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 .75em .75em; 
    background: black;
    position:relative;
}
.box1 {
    background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 50% / 0.75em;
    bottom: -1px;
    height: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30em;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgp6jdpm/) example for the above code its working fine :)