# CSS How to generate this Shape on a Div or on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

i have been trying for like 3 hours to make this shape [image]

on a div using css

Canvas drawing is accepted , but Css is prefered

Thanks guys :D

---

**Another Solution**

if any one is looking for the Canvas solution or the non-solid background here is it https://jsfiddle.net/roonie007/hemjfonx/1/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var curveStrength = 50 ;


context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 0);
context.quadraticCurveTo(canvas.width/2, curveStrength, canvas.width, 0);
context.lineTo(canvas.width,canvas.height);
context.lineTo(0,canvas.height);
context.lineTo(0,0);

context.fillStyle = "black";
context.fill();
```

Comment: Is using backgrounds acceptable? ( in css )

Comment: if it's not a picture i am ok :D

Comment: What do you need it for? Just curious.

Comment: Refer this: [CSS: Rectangle side to round inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925208/css-rectangle-side-to-round-inside)

Comment: i will use it as a footer like this one http://clipart.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/n029-preview.jpg it looks really nice

Comment: Sadly, you won't be able to use jayms' answer for that.

Comment: if you are talking about the background white color , i will change it to the Body background color and it will work

Comment: If you have only solid color in footer's background then yes. It will be ok. But with any image/content/anything - no.

Comment: @Green Check my question update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be useful to know what kind of shape that is. I am cutting an ellipse in half for my solution.

This was kind of fun.

Edit: Changed my code a little bit to look crisper.

```css
#box {
  width:300px;
  height:50px;
  background:black;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#box::before{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  height:30px;
  background:white;
  border-radius:0 0 50% 50%;
  position:relative;
  top:-15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you do this with one box using :before{} ?

Comment: if you can that would be really awsome :D

Comment: thanks guys it works perfectly , i will change some values to adapt it